# MS Graph API - adding event creates a meeting, not an event instance

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm using the Microsoft Graph JavaScript Client Library to add events to other user's calendars but they are being added as meetings. How do I ensure they are added as events?

The payload looks like this:

```
 {
        location: {
            displayName: 'Office'
        },
        subject: 'Test',
        body: {
            contentType: 'Text',
            content: 'Test'
        },
        start: {
            dateTime: '2023-03-17T15:00:00',
            timeZone: 'GMT Standard Time'
        },
        end: {
            dateTime: '2023-03-17T16:00:00',
            timeZone: 'GMT Standard Time'
        }    
}
```

And the call to the graph client:

```
await client
    .api(`/users/someone@somewhere.com/calendar/events`)
    .post(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an event to another user's calendar using the Microsoft Graph JavaScript Client Library, you need to make sure that you set the isOrganizer property of the event to true.

Try this sample code:

```js
// Initialize the Microsoft Graph client
const client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
    authProvider: (done) => {
        // Authenticate using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)
        // See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-javascript
        // for more information on how to authenticate using MSAL
        done(null, accessToken);
    }
});

// Define the new event
const newEvent = {
    subject: 'Your event subject',
    start: {
        dateTime: '2023-03-24T09:00:00',
        timeZone: 'Pacific Standard Time'
    },
    end: {
        dateTime: '2023-03-24T10:00:00',
        timeZone: 'Pacific Standard Time'
    },
    isOrganizer: true // Set this property to true to create a new event instead of a meeting
};

// Create the new event on the specified user's calendar
client
    .api('/users/{userId}/calendar/events')
    .version('v1.0')
    .post(newEvent, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(`New event created: ${res.id}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have discovered the issue. I was adding attendees to the request. Outlook interprets this as a meeting instead of an event. Removing the attendees results in the event being added as an appointment.